# Find the density of the random variable $\frac{1}{X}$ given that $X$ has a continuous density function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I found the following question kind of counterintuitive (it is a question from a probability theory book). I feel it is hard to claim $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}]$ has an infinite expectation without knowing the distribution of $X$ (the only thing we know is that $X$ has a continuous density function):

Let $\xi$ be a random variable with a continuous density $p_{\xi}$ such that $p_{\xi}(0) \geq 0$. Find the density of $\eta$, where
\begin{equation*}
    \eta(\omega) = 
    \begin{cases}
        1/\xi(\omega) \ \text{ if } \xi(\omega) \neq 0 \\
        0  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ if } \xi(\omega) = 0 \\
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq: state}
\end{equation*}

Prove that $\eta$ does not have a finite expectation.

Also, any suggestions on how to find the distribution of $\eta$?

Comment: Have you tried [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)?

Comment: If the density function of $\xi =0$ in a neighborhood of $0$, then $E(\frac{1}{\xi})$ would not necessarily be infinite.

Comment: There is a typo in the question. It should be "$p_{\xi}$ such that $p_{\xi}(0) > 0$"

Answer (score 1):

Use the Jacobian method. Let $f_X(x)$ be the density of $X=\epsilon$ and $f_Y (y)$ be the density of $Y = \eta$  (I find writing greeks tiresome...)

Then $Y = X^{-1}$ which can be inverted to obtain $X = Y^{-1}$

This transforation is one-to-one and continuous almost everywhere (It's only discontinuous/undefined at $X=0$ which has probability $0$). Hence

$J = \frac{d}{dy} y^{-1} = -y^{-2}$

And so the pdf of $Y$ is given by

$$f_Y (y) = |-y^{-2}| f_X (y^{-1}) = y^{-2}f_X (y^{-1})$$

To show $Y$ has non-finite expectation, since $P(X \neq Y)=0$ I think you should write it as

$$E[Y] = \int x^{-1} f_X (x)dx$$

and make an argument that $E[Y]$ must be infinite since $x^{-1}f_X(x)$ diverges at $0$ (but is defined since $Y = 0$ at $X=0$ by construction). Since we are told $f_X (x) > 0$ then you can show the limit doesn't exist fairly easily, since $f(x)$ converges to a finite positive constant, while $x^{-1}$ diverges and is undefined at $0$.

Comment: Thanks! The inequality is actually strict (I just modified the question). One more question why $f_Y(y)$ is related to $f_X(x)$, aka. why $f_Y(y)=|−y^{−2}|f_X(y^{−1})$? Many thanks!

Comment: It's a well known method of finding the density of transformations. I would recommend reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables) . Alternatively, for a more indepth explanation, try [this book, pages 157-158](https://fsalamri.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/casella_berger_statistical_inference1.pdf)

Comment: This solution has mistakes. This transformation has 2 parts, one is decreasing, the other part is increasing. And the y range is different in these 2 parts.